# Recycler View to change View Holders

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I use a RecyclerView to display a list of items. The RecyclerView shows a single item at the time. By clicking a button I would like to change ViewHolders for all the items, including the one displayed. The data stays the same, only the list item layout changes.

I supposed I need to clear the cache pool, but it did not help. There are still views in the recycler pool.

```
recyclerView.recycledViewPool.clear()
```

RecyclerView keeps using the cached views.
Moreover, how to re-create the view with a new ViewHolder of the item displayed?

Comment: No . you need to change the ViewType for those elements you wants to change and then notify the adapter accordingly . Clearing `ViewPool` will not work in this case . `ViewPool` works with ViewType Only if you don't change `ViewType` the ViewHolder won't change .

Answer (score 1):

add type in your model class

```
var viewType : ViewType
```

make an enum of viewType

```
ViewType { VIEW_ONE, VIEW_TWO }
```

override `ItemViewType` function in your `RecyclerViewAdapter`. Make separate Layout files for each view type and create/inflate in `onCreateViewHolder` of `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

When button is being pressed. Change the `ViewType` in your model class and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: It's better to use `notifyItemChanged(position)`